# R: Select the first non-NA data for each row, within an arbitrarily long subset of variables

Tags: r, dplyr, data-analysis, quasiquotes

I'm trying to write a function in R; let's call it `favor()`. It needs to accept an arbitrary number of columns of a tibble, which may not contain complete data. For each row in the dataset, `favor()` will examine the contents of each column provided (in the order provided) and "favor" the first one which contains a non-missing value, copying that value to a new column and returning the resulting dataset. So, for an input dataset that looks like this:

```
data <- tibble(
          a = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
          b = c(NA, NA, 7, NA),
          c = c(9, NA, 11, NA)
         )

# The output should look something like this:

result <- favor(data, b, c, a)

> result
# A tibble: 4 × 4
      a     b     c favored
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1    NA     9       9
2     2    NA    NA       2
3     3     7    11       7
4     4    NA    NA       4
```

This is easy enough to do when you have a set number of variables to look through; the difficulty is that I want this to work for an arbitrarily large subset of columns from the input dataset. I seems that dot-dot-dot notation will need to be used, so I think the function header will look something like:

```
favor <- function(data, ...) {}
```

But beyond this I'm a little stumped on what the best way to implement this would be. I'm working with dplyr, so I've tried thinking about something like:

```
favor <- function(data, ...) {

  result <- data %>%
    mutate(favor = first(na.omit({{ ... }})))

}
```

But this doesn't seem to work, I think because this isn't the right way to do embrasure around `...`.  So, what's the right approach for this mapping function? Do I need to loop over all rows in `data` and all values in `...`?  Is there something more clever I can do, using proper quasi-quotation?

A few requirements about my use case I want to note:

- The arguments passed to `...` will be given in the desired priority. So `..1` would be favored if it has non-missing data, `..2` will be favored if `..1` is missing, and so on.
- Not all variables passed to `...` will necessarily be of the same data type. `favor()` should be able to work even if it receives a character column, a numeric column, and a date column to choose between.
- Ideally this will end up in a package— I've already taken the dplyr dependency, but would like to avoid too many others (if possible! If the base R + dplyr solution is very messy but there's a simple alternative, I would certainly consider it.)

And, if it helps to conceptualize this as a more specific use case: one use of this will be to choose a date from multiple date columns that may contain missing data. In a dataset of events, date column A might be the most accurate date to use to represent that event, but if it's missing, then date column B is the next best proxy, date column C is the next best proxy after that, and so on.

I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65685388/select-first-non-na-value-using-r) comes the closest to what I'm asking (and the use of `first()` is probably a good lead), but my data won't be grouped and again, I need this to work for an arbitrary number of columns.

Comment: When you say, "Not all variables passed to `...` will necessarily be of the same data type do you mean within a call (eg `favor(data, date, number, character)`) or between calls (eg `favor(data, num1, num2)`, `favor(data, date1, date2)`?

Comment: @LMc Within a call, so `favor(data, date, number, character)` might be a valid use case here.

Comment: That might be something better handled by the user before your function. They should choose how to coerce the columns, if they want the columns coerced at all. There is a reason this type of behavior throws an error in the `tidyverse` as it is generally safer to error and force the user to decide the best way to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)

favor <- function(data, ...) {
  data |>
    mutate(favored = coalesce(!!!ensyms(...)))
}

favor(data, b, c, a)
# a     b     c favored
# <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1     1    NA     9       9
# 2     2    NA    NA       2
# 3     3     7    11       7
# 4     4    NA    NA       4
```

`?coalesce` does exactly what you are looking for:

> Given a set of vectors, coalesce() finds the first non-missing value at each position.

You simply need to unpack your ellipsis into the function call:

```r
favor <- function(data, ...) {
  data |>
    mutate(favored = coalesce(!!!ensyms(...))) |>
    rlang::qq_show()
}

favor(data, b, c, a)
# mutate(data, favored = coalesce(b, c, a))

favor(data, c, b, a)
# mutate(data, favored = coalesce(c, b, a))
```

Comment: Looks like this works perfectly, except in the case where different columns have different data types— that'll come back with an error like `Can't combine '..1' <double> and '..2' <character>`

Comment: @seaweedbrain that will be the case whatever method you use. A column in a data frame or tibble can only have a single type, so `favored` will always be a single type, determined by the implicit conversion of all the other columns.

Comment: Oh, that makes complete sense!  Thanks for the explainer @AllanCameron, and for the elegant solution @ LMc.  This will totally work.

Answer (score 1):

A base R method would be something like:

```r
favor <- function(data, ...) {
  ss <- data[sapply(as.list(match.call())[-(1:2)], deparse)]
  within(data, favored <- apply(ss, 1, \(x) na.omit(x)[1]))
}
```

Giving you

```r
favor(data, b, c, a)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>       a     b     c favored
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1     1    NA     9       9
#> 2     2    NA    NA       2
#> 3     3     7    11       7
#> 4     4    NA    NA       4
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>